# Парсинг XML API

Tags: python, xml

Есть апи в котором содержиться код.

```
<response>
    <item>
        <id>663</id>
        <stationID>1139</stationID>
        <placeID>636</placeID>
        <hasFuel>false</hasFuel>
        <hasPetrol>false</hasPetrol>
        <descriptionPetrol/>
        <hasDiesil>false</hasDiesil>
        <descriptionDiesil/>
        <hasGas>false</hasGas>
        <descriptionGas/>
        <updated>1721</updated>
            <station>
            <id>1239</id>
            <networkID>3</networkID>
            <placeID>626</placeID>
            <stationID>B11</stationID>
            <name>Имя</name>
            <status>1</status>
            <longitude>342.2561</longitude>
            <latitude>448.5774</latitude>
            </station>
    </item>
```

таких и там еще пару item

```
response = requests.get(config.FUEL).text
```

я сделал запрос, какие дальше мои действия.

Comment: Открыть гугл, вбить в строку запроса "python xml парсинг" и наслаждаться результатами поиска?

Comment: та просто есть разные варианты import xml.dom.minidom, import xml.etree.ElementTree каким лучше это делать?

Comment: Какой вам больше понравится

Comment: response = requests.get(config.FUEL).text
data = ET.fromstring(response) xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
Или уже не нужно писать ET.fromstring(response)